# Oracle: Import existing table from dmp into new table

Tags: oracle, shell, impdp

I was able to export the table using below command

```
exp usr1/user1@tes tables=table1 file=/myfoler/export/parties.dmp log=/myfoler/export/parties.log statistics=none direct=y
```

But when I am trying to import the dmp file into new table it is failing

```
imp usr1/user1@tes file=/myfoler/export/parties.dmp buffer=131072 commit=y log=/myfoler/export/parties_imp.log feedback=1000 ignore=Y tables=export_test
```

I am getting below error while doing so

> IMP-00033: Warning: Table "EXPORT_TEST" not found in export file

Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong?  I want to import the dump into new table which is already created.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use the `REMAP_TABLE` option

```
REMAP_TABLE=[schema.]old_tablename[.partition]:new_tablename
```

Comment: i believe if you use impdp you can use the same schema just so long as the new tablename does not already exists. The REMAP_TABLE option is not available using imp, i think then you would need to import into a new temp schema and then do a CTAS into the original schema with the new tablename